# JavaScript method to over-ride default behaviour of object destructuring

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Is there a way in JS to over-ride the default behavior of an object when it is de-structured?

```
// Normally destructing lifts properties from an object
const foo = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};

const { a, b } = foo; // a = 1, b = 2

// I would like to have a method return the properties to be
// destructured
const bar = {
  toObject: () => {
    return { a, b };
  },
};

const { a, b } = bar; // a = undefiner, b = undefined
```

I know that I could simply use `const { a, b } = bar.toObject();` but that requires the consumer of the object to know how it's internals work and breaks the principle of least astonishment.

The closest thing I can think of to what I want is the [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) magic method.

Comment: where are the values of `a` and `b` coming from in the function?

Comment: "*but that requires the consumer of the object to know how it's internals work*" destructuring *already* requires knowing how the internals work. But only in terms of knowing what properties there are to know what to destructure. So I'd counter your statement that you now require the *object* to know *how it's going to be destructured* which is more problematic than needing to know that an object has keys `a` and `b`.

Comment: what is your actual usecase?

Comment: My use case is that I'm re-writing an existing class to use private variables. For now I'm using the `Object.freeze` method, because it allows for de-structuring (which is widely used in my app), but I'd rather use the constructor local method (as I don't believe the properties should be exposed). I will be the first to admit that the difference is slight. This question was more for my curiosity (since I couldn't find anything in the docs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The specification [requires](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation) the right hand side to resolve to a value that can be converted to an object via [`ToObject`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-toobject), which simply returns the object itself if it is passed one (i.e. no special method on the object is called to convert it to something else).

[image]

Comment: I think OP meant `toObject` as something that works similar as `toString` - the method that gets called when doing `"some string" + someObject`

Comment: @VLAZ: Sure. And I'm saying that the only "transformation" that happens to the value is that `ToObject` (the internal algorithm) is called, which simply returns object values "as is". It does not check whether the object has a specific method and calls that.

Comment: Yea, I suspected as much. Effectively I'm looking for a way to over-ride `ToObject` which JS doesn't support. It is a shame.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd use array destructuring, that would work:

```
 const [a, b] = {
   *[Symbol.iterator]() {
     yield "some"; yield "stuff";
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `toObject` work as intended by decorating the target with a Proxy that intercepts `ownKeys` and `get` to fake an object for destructuring:

```js
let withToObject = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
    ownKeys(o) {
        return Object.keys(o.toObject())
    },
    get(o, prop) {
        return o.toObject()[prop]
    }
});

let bar = withToObject({
    aa: 11,
    bb: 22,
    cc: 33,

    toObject() {
        return {
            a: this.aa,
            b: this.bb
        };
    }
});

const {a, b} = bar;

console.log(a, b)
```

Of course, this affects not only destructuring, but also any other interaction with the object, like serialization, so you have to take measures to make these work too. For example, to support JSON, patch `get` like this:

```
get(o, prop) {
    if (prop === 'toJSON')
        return () => o; // or o.toObject(), whatever fits better
    return o.toObject()[prop]
```

Comment: I assume this has many bad side effects ... nevertheless it works, great idea :)

Comment: This works as per my phrasing, but it does expose the properties `a` and `b` before de-structuring (e.g `bar.a === 11`)

Comment: @thelastshadow: yes, it does... destructuring is just a syntax sugar, `{a} = x` is the same as `a = x.a`